# Game engine used for iPhone Zombie Cafe?

Tags: iphone

There is a game called Zombie Cafe, for iPhone. It is 2d and has a cool concept. Developed by capcommobile.

Anyway, all I want to know is what engine did they use for making it?
I know that this kind of game could be done using pretty much any engine, but I am particularly interested in capcommobile's approach. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Short of insider information, it would be pretty hard to give the "correct" answer.  It would be better to ask about specific effects or whatever in a game that you want to achieve so we could give you pointers on how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as it's Capcom, it's most likely that they used a bespoke engine that they created themselves. I'm not familiar with the game itself, but with fairly few stable engines for mobile development currently out there and not many big developers using something like Unity at the minute, I would say they just made it themselves.

It's Capcom, they have A LOT of code and experience, so I don't think it would be a massive challenge for them (unless the game has some crazy stuff in it, which is a challenge for anybody).